# Change UIViewController self.view frame

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to display a viewController xib view with its view displayed under a fixed header  banner (0,0,320,44) which is an imageView added on Application window.

This is because I need it to stick on the screen while I navigate multiple view controllers. Its a requirement of the project I am doing.

So far I have tried:

- Resizing the XIB view to the appropriate frame size (0,0,320,416), both with dot notation and setter.
- Changing the frame in viewDidLoad with self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 416);

but it is not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: why you are adding the imageview on Application window.you can add it in viewController xib.

Comment: @Mudit: I need it to stick on the screen while I navigate multiple view controllers. Its a requirement of the project I am doing.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to use multiple view controllers? Seems to me you only need multiple views. In any case you can leave default full screen view controller views and add subviews below header banner. In the case of only 1 view controller there is less work then in case of multiple.

Comment: @Matic you are right but I want to use xibs and I don't want to mess in loading xibs from bundle at runtime, this is why I am choosing this way. Otherwise, you are totally right, I could have been using only programmatically-built views and the resize would have been easier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the frame in `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 416);
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks, but why? The frame is not yet drawn in viewDidLoad? Just want to understand better, and also would love not to have to draw this every time the view appears.

Comment: I believe self.view.frame is overrided at the end of viewDidLoad (from iOS side), just before viewWillAppear call.

Comment: it seems that what's also quite important is to set the frame before `[super viewWillAppear];`

Comment: Saved my life! Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work to me! in viewDidLoad, the frame is not changed

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add a bit more. The reason for changing view of a UIViewController does not work in `viewDidLoad` is because of the call `[window makeKeyAndVisible]`, which is usually called after your `viewDidLoad`. This call will change the frame of the `window.rootViewController` to equal the window's frame. You can test this by changing the UIViewController's view.frame AFTER `[window makeKeyAndVisible]`, and the changes will stick.

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are called within `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` but after the view's frame got resized.

The caveat is that only the top most controller which is the `rootViewController` has its view's frame changed automatically. This DOES NOT affect any `childViewControllers` attached to the `rootViewController`.